# Elasticsearch geo_distance in combination with other queries

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello I have a problem with the combination of multiple queries within Elasticsearch.

The problem only occurs whenever I try to combine a `multi_match query` with the `geo_distance query`. The multi_match query works when the `geo_distance query` is not present and the `geo_distance query` works when the `multi_match query` is not present.

Whenever I execute the `multi_match query` without the `geo_distance query` I get the results that I expect. I also get the expected results when I try the `geo_distance query` without the `multi_match query`.

Boths results contain the dataset that I would expect to receive when both queries are executed together. But whenever I execute them together I receive 0 results.

When I combine the `geo_distance query` with a simple `term query` the search works. So I presume it is problem with the combination of queries.

I would appreciate any ideas.

---

My query is the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "should": {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "CompanyName GmbH",
              "fields": [
                "originalName",
                "legalName"
              ],
              "type": "cross_fields",
              "operator": "AND"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": {
            "geo_distance": {
              "location": [
                9.87107,
                51.69915
              ],
              "distance": "30.0km",
              "distance_type": "arc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

The mapping behind all of that is:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "aliases": {

    },
    "mappings": {
      "customer-entity": {
        "properties": {
          "communication": {
            "properties": {
              "domain": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "email": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "landline": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "mobile": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "legalName": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": true
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          },
          "operatingModes": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "originalName": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": true
          }
        }
      },
      "homepage-entity": {
        "_parent": {
          "type": "customer-entity"
        },
        "_routing": {
          "required": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "customerId": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": true
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "metas": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": true
          }
        }
      },
      "person-entity": {
        "_parent": {
          "type": "customer-entity"
        },
        "_routing": {
          "required": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "customerId": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": true
          },
          "firstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": true
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": true
          },
          "personId": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "refresh_interval": "-1",
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "creation_date": "1488920698118",
        "store": {
          "type": "fs"
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "0",
        "uuid": "ZcLN5sxASXGUnKZMg8mBpw",
        "version": {
          "created": "2040499"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers": {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried without the nested `bool/should` queries?

Comment: Yes I also have tried it without the nested `bool/should queries` however it didn't work either.

Comment: Weird, no reason it wouldn't work without the two `bool/should` queries. You can remove them as they are just noise.

Comment: Yeah it should work, as I receive a result when I switch the multi_match query with a term query. I presume it is a problem with the multi_match query in combination with the geo_distance query.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't get the same documents when querying with `multi_match` or `term`, right? So the reason would be that the document you get with `multi_match` are not in the requested distance.

Comment: In this case I get the same documents as the `multi_match query` only matches exactly one document and I created the `term query` so that I would match exactly the one document I would receive with the `multi_match` query.
In fact I can create a `term query` on any field and I get some results, but as soon as I use a `multi_match query` on any field together with the `geo_distance query` I do not get any results.